# How to add Apache directory lib in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, apache-directory

I want to use the Apache directory lib in my android application, according to their site all you need is to add the org.apache.directory.api:api-all dependency in maven. By using Maven repository I got the following gradle equivalent:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.api/api-all';
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.directory.api', name: 'api-all', version: '1.0.0-RC1'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.msi.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
```

When running the library downloads, but when running it gives the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have tried to clean and rebuild the project, I also manually deleted all the build files. Futhermore, I have tried  with and without the: 
multiDexEnabled true and the dexOptions. This gives the same error. I have also tried extracting the all the jars into one jar file and include this into the project. This gives:

```
com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException
```

The question is quick and easy, how can I add the Apache Directory lib to my project in any way?